# how to add some icon to the grid layout

Tags: java

I am trying to add an icon for frame to make 8queen problem, but this code doesn't work:

```
public class FrameTest {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
//    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("chessQueens.png");
//    JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);

    public void printFrame() {

        jf.add(jp);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        JLabel j2 = new JLabel();
        JLabel j3 = new JLabel();
        JLabel j4 = new JLabel();
        jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(2, 4, 4));

            jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chessQueens.png"));
            j2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chessQueens.png"));
            j3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chessQueens.png"));
            j4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chessQueens.png"));

            jp.add(jl);
            jf.add(jp);

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. What do you mean by : It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. You're calling `setVisible()` before adding the elements to the frame. This will cause the element not to display unless you revalidate(). Call `setVisible()` last.
2. The panel in the `JFrame` should be set with `setContentPane()`, rather than `add()`
3. Use a loop to instantiate instead for compactness.

The following code works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class T {
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  JPanel jp = new JPanel();
  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("chessQueens.png");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    T t = new T();
  }

  public T() {
    printFrame();
  }

  public void printFrame() {
    jf.add(jp);
    jf.setSize(500, 500);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(2, 4, 4));
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
      JLabel jl = new JLabel();
      jl.setIcon(image);
      jp.add(jl);
    }
    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    jf.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```